# How to handle different account types in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, model, schema

I have a 3 tables/models with the relationship illustrated below:

```
    Account
       |
   ----------
   |        |
 User     Company
```

They are all joined by the the Account's PRIMARY KEY, and the User and Company each have very different sets of methods and fields.

Assuming that I only know the "account id", and I need to load an account, I am assuming that the following is a good procedure?

1. the Account model is loaded by id
2. the "account type" is then determined
3. either a User or a Company object is loaded into the Account object itself. It could be used like so:

   $account->company->company_name();

Somehow this doesn't seem very efficient...can somebody suggest something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to have both User and Company extend Account, and with the parent class Account not knowing about the children classes (only the child classes should know about the parent class) so when you need to add more Account subclasses, you don't need to change anything in Account:

```
    class Account {
        var $email;
        var $password;

        function load() {
            // load from db
        }
    }

    class User extends Account {
        var $first_name;
        var $last_name;

        function load() {
            parent::load();
            // load for this class
        }
    }

    class Company extends Account {
        var $company_name;

        function load() {
            parent::load();
            // load for this class
        }
    }
```

Comment: That makes total sense...the only problem I run into is - what if I don't know ahead of time if the account is for a user or company?

Comment: Can you give an example?  I guess if you can defer the instantiation of the object, then just defer until the type of account is known, or, if it's not an issue to change the object at runtime, then just change the object to the new one (from Account to User, for example).